# DOM reading in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a filter that will show or hide `<div>` regarding the `data-type` they have in their tags.

Here is my Javascript :

```
var course_difficulty_level_filter= function(el,level) 
  {
    this.el = el;
    this.el.closest('#courses_content').find("div").hide();
    if(level != "00"){
      this.el.closest('#courses_content').find('div[data-difficulty="'+level+'"]').show();
      console.log("show difficulty_level : "+ level);
    } else {
      this.el.closest('#courses_content').find("div").show();
      console.log("show difficulty_level : all");
    };
  }

$('#course_filter_level1').click(function(){

  $(this).click(course_difficulty_level_filter($(this),"1"));

});
```

And here is my HTML :

```
<div id="coursefilter">
    <div id="coursefilter_content" class="hide">

        <div id="coursefilter_content_text">
            <div id="course_filter_level_text"><p class="course_filter">Level: </p></div>       
        </div>

        <div id="coursefilter_content_icons">
            <div id="course_filter_level">
                <div id="course_filter_level1" class="opacityquarter"> 
                    <div id="level1_rectangle1"></div>
                    <div id="level1_rectangle2"></div>
                    <div id="level1_rectangle3"></div>
                    <div id="level1_rectangle4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Courses - Course Overviews-->
<div id="courses">
    <div id="courses_content" class="hide">
        <div class="course_overview_content_even" data-difficulty="1" data-lang="en"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I successfully get the `console.log => show difficulty_level : 1`, so my script is "working", but I think it can't navigate trough the DOM, but I don't find why.

Comment: You are trying to bind a `click` event handler to the element that was just clicked? What's the point of that? Also: You are calling `course_difficulty_level_filter` instead of passing it to `$(this).click`, so the binding won't work. If you just want to call `course_difficulty_level_filter`, then do that and remove the `$(this).click` part. As it currently is, `this` inside the function refers to the global object. If it was an event handler it would refer to the DOM element, so what's the point of assigning `el` to the global object or a DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code is the problem:

```
this.el.closest('#courses_content')
```

The [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function works back up the parents to find the selector, but `#courses_content` is not a parent of `#course_filter_level1` (the value passed in as `el`).

Try changing those references to just be:

```
$('#courses_content')
```

There should be no need to find this element relative to the passed in element as I hope there is only one div with the id `courses_content` as ID's are supposed to be unique within the document.

The whole function can be changed to this:

```
// removed el, so it must be removed from the calling function
var course_difficulty_level_filter= function(level) 
{
    var coursesContent = $('#courses_content');
    coursesContent.find("div").hide();
    if(level != "00"){
        coursesContent.find('div[data-difficulty="'+level+'"]').show();
        console.log("show difficulty_level : "+ level);
    } else {
        coursesContent.find("div").show();
        console.log("show difficulty_level : all");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you simply looking for:

```
$('div[data-difficulty="'+level+'"]').show();
$('div[data-difficulty="'+level+'"]').hide();
```

jQuery has rich support for querying HTML attibutes: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: Chris Hardie has a good point. The code above is borderline unreadable and I would recommend a good jQuery study session.